# local file paths does not work inside v-lazy-image

Tags: css, vue.js

For my page banner I use v-lazy-image plugin. I need to include local image files for that. But it does not work.

```
<v-lazy-image
      srcset="../../../assets/images/banners/Small-Banner.svg 320w, ../../../assets/images/banners/Big-Banner.svg 480w"
    sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px, 440px"
    src="../../../assets/images/banners/Big-Banner.svg"
      />
```

But its work for external links. Like below.

```
<v-lazy-image
      srcset="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/25/17/55/color-2174045_960_720.png 320w, https://blah/blah.png 480w"
    sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px, 440px"
    src="https://blah/blah.png"
      />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the image in your component. Not sure if there's a better way for `srcset`, but this is how you would do it using `src`.

EDIT: Updated to handle `srcset`

```html
<template>
    <img :src="banner" :srcset="bannerSizes" alt="Hero Image" />
</template>

<script>
import banner from "@/assets/images/banners/Small-Banner.svg";

export default {
    computed: {
        banner() {
            return banner;
        },
        bannerSizes() {
            return `
               ${this.size(this.banner, "300")}, 
               ${this.size(this.banner, "1440")}
            `;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        size(image, width) {
            return `${image} ${width}w`;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```